# Circle two terms in an equation linking them by an arrow in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, circles, tikzmark

I'd like to know if it's possible to do something like that in an equation.

[image]

My code here

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
 %\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}         
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

 \newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
\node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=1pt] (#1) {#2};}


 \begin{document}

$$\tikzmark{a}{a}=\tikzmark{c}{c}$$

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (a.north) to [bend left=45] node[anchor=south]{$=$}(c.north);}

\end{document}
```

I don't know the draw arrows at the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What exactly is the problem that you try to solve? Your code already does what you want; you just have to draw the second arrow in the same way as you draw the first one. By the way, replace `$$....$$` by `\[...\]`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It looks like you've got two separate accounts (given the suggested edit I just saw), which means you cannot directly edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Basically you have just to duplicate the code for the upper arrow and replace `north` by `south` and `left` by `right`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}         
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

 \newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
\node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=1pt] (#1) {#2};}


 \begin{document}

\[\tikzmark{a}{a}=\tikzmark{c}{c}\]

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->]
   (a.north) to [bend left=45] node[above]{\scriptsize$=$}(c.north);}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->]
   (a.south) to [bend right=45] node[below]{\scriptsize$=$}(c.south);}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{graphics}
\newcommand{\arroweqover}{\substack{\mathstrut \mkern7mu=\\ \scalebox{2.5}{$\mkern4mu\curvearrowright$}}}

\newcommand{\arrowequnder}{\substack{\rotatebox{180}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\mkern-4mu\curvearrowleft$}}\\ \mathstrut\mkern7mu=}}

\begin{document}
\[
 \overset{\arroweqover}{\underset{\arrowequnder}{A=c}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]